# Coefficient of volume expansion for gases

Tags: thermodynamics, ideal-gas

I often read that at 0 degree (Centigrade), gases expand by 1/273 of its volume at 0 degree for one degree rise in temp. So does this coefficient of expansion ( i.e. 1/273) change with temperature?

Comment: How many Kelvin is 0 degrees Celsius?

Comment: @JonCuster 273.15 K

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does depend on temperature.

$PV = nRT$

so

$V \propto  T$

or volume is proportional to temperature in Kelvin.

To go from 0 degrees Centrigrade to 1 degree Centrigrade the temperature in Kelvin changes from 273 K to 274 K (approximately) so the volume changes from $V$ to ${274 \over 273} V$ which is equal to $(1 + {1 \over 273}) V$ - so there is an increase of ${1 \over 273} V$.

Note in this rise of ${1 \over 273} V$ the $273$ comes from the initial temperature of $273 K$ so that if the temperature were say 100 Centigrade or $373 K$ the factor  would be $1 \over 373$

Finally, note that Temperature in Kelvin = Temperature in Centigrade +273 (approximately)